# UIHint Attribute in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-uihint

What is Use of UIHint Attribute in MVC . Can anyone please provide me a simple example of how to use it and what it does.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When using a Display or Editor template, UIHint will tell it which template to use:

```
[UIHint("SomeTemplate")]
public class MyViewModel
{
     public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If you create a Display template called SomeTemplate.ascx (since you are MVC2) in the Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates or Views/{Controller}/DisplayTemplates then it will use that template when you do:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel() // if Model is MyViewModel
```

or

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ModelProperty) // if ModelProperty is of type MyViewModel
```

**edit**
If you want to specify this on a property level:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [UIHint("Birthday")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

You could create a display/editor template called Birthday in the DisplayTemplates or EditorTemplates folder in either /Views/Shared or /Views/{Controller}. Then when you do:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
```

or

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
```

It will use the template specified in UIHint

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Great!! But How t specify on Property level ..need more clear representation please

Comment: Dang it, that was exactly what I spent an hour looking for how to do. Why do they make it that hard to find this property?

Comment: Cannot be used on a `class`, only on properties and fields.

Comment: Your example `[UIHint("SomeTemplate")]` raises a compiler error "_Attribute 'UIHint' is not valid on this declaration type.  It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations._"

Answer (score 15):

UIHint can only be used on a property not on a class declaration as Dismissile states. I am using MVC3 so this may have changed from MVC2.

"Attribute 'UIHint' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations"