# Define a DisplayTemplate for a Custom Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, display-templates

Is it possible to specify the Display Template name when defining a *property* Type?

For example, I have some classes:

```
public interface IFoo {}
public class Foo : IFoo {}
public class Bar : IFoo {}
```

Then I have a Model:

```
public class MyModel{
    IFoo IFooExample {get;set;}
}
```

Then I want to render `IFooExample` in my View:

```
@model MyModel

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.IFooExample)
```

`Foo` and `Bar` can share the same Display Template, ie `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/IFoo.cshtml`.  How can I plug this logic into Mvc so that I don't have to either a) create `Foo.cshtml` and `Bar.cshtml` or b) from my View call `DisplayFor` with an overload for the view (`@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.IFooExample, "IFoo.cshtml")` ).

I also don't want to decorate my Model with a UIHint attribute. I'd really like to specify the information on the definition of `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
[UIHint("IFoo.cshtml")]
public class Foo : IFoo{}

[UIHint("IFoo.cshtml")]
public class Bar : IFoo{}
```

But `UIHint`s [can't be applied at the class level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154360/1224069).  So is there another way to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to create a new `DisplayFor` HtmlHelper extension method which is specific to the interface `IFoo`, and, inside it, display the desired template. For example:

```
public static class DisplayForExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, IFoo>> propertySelector)
    {
        return html.DisplayFor(propertySelector, "IFoo.cshtml");
    }
}
```

This extension method is more specific than the original ones, which accept any kind of value, not specifically an `IFoo` property.

Remember that this extension method must be visible in your razor templates. To do so you can:

- include the namespace with an `@using` in each desired Razor template
- include it in the `web.config`, creating a new `<add namespace="Your extension class namespace" />` under `<namespaces>`, so that it's available to all razor templates